# Expressing observations in regression

Tags: regression, sas

Suppose we are using logistic regression on a binary outcome variable $Y$ with two continuous predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$. Suppose the observation $Y = 1, X_1 = 10, X_2 = 15$ occurs 1000 times. In SAS, how would you account for this frequency in the regression without having to manually type the observation 1000 times?

**Edit.** I figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Use [FREQ](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect013.htm) option. The code look like

```
  proc logistic data=datax;
  freq f;
  model Y= X1 X2;
  run;
```

where in f variable you can provide the frequency.